# EWW very slow opening of certain pages

Tags: performance, eww, web-browser, rendering

This question was asked on stackoverflow. Just cross posting it here for better visibility. I am too facing the same issue.

I'm using EWW Emacs browser for opening various remote pages(mostly documentation) which is very handy most of the time.

I'm still trying to understand why certain pages take 4-5-6+ seconds to be rendered in eww(which take <1s in Chrome, for comparison).

For my tasks, I only care about the loaded content - images and fancy styles are not needed.

Is there any simple way to speed it up? Like setting readable mode/disabling images before calling eww? If that's possible at all.

I did some basic profiling and its seems the eww-render is lost spending time in recursive descend. Does this give any idea what could be amiss here?

```
- url-http-generic-filter                                        5103  39%
 - url-http-content-length-after-change-function                 4998  38%
  - url-http-activate-callback                                   4871  37%
   - apply                                                       4871  37%
    - eww-render                                                 4667  35%
     - eww-display-html                                          4659  35%
      - shr-insert-document                                      3725  28%
       - shr-descend                                             3292  25%
        - shr-tag-base                                           3292  25%
         - shr-descend                                           3292  25%
          - shr-tag-html                                         3292  25%
           - shr-descend                                         3292  25%
            - shr-tag-body                                       3292  25%
             - shr-descend                                       3292  25%
              - shr-tag-div                                      3288  25%
               - shr-descend                                     3288  25%
                - shr-tag-div                                    3288  25%
                 - shr-descend                                   3288  25%
                  - shr-tag-div                                  3212  24%
                   - shr-descend                                 3212  24%
                    - shr-descend                                3208  24%
                     - shr-descend                               3124  23%
                      - shr-tag-div                              3124  23%
                       - shr-descend                             3124  23%
                        - shr-descend                            3084  23%
                         - shr-tag-div                           3084  23%
                          - shr-descend                          3084  23%
                           - shr-tag-div                         3084  23%
                            - shr-descend                        3084  23%
                             - shr-tag-div                       3084  23%
                              - shr-descend                      3084  23%
                               - shr-tag-div                     3084  23%
                                - shr-descend                    3084  23%
                                 - shr-tag-div                   3023  23%
                                  - shr-descend                  3023  23%
                                   - shr-tag-div                 1604  12%
                                    - shr-descend                1604  12%
                                     - shr-descend               1428  10%
                                      + shr-tag-table               1377  10%
                                      + eww-tag-a                  47   0%
                                        shr-tag-div                  4   0%
                                     + shr-tag-div                176   1%
                                   + shr-descend                 1407  10%
                                   + eww-tag-a                      8   0%
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from SO.

Comment: why not close the SO question instead? Its more relevant here.

Comment: Did you open the SO question? If so feel free to close that instead. But having the same question in two places is not a good idea.

Comment: No, I didn't. Let me ask the original poster to close the SO question.

Comment: what web page are you trying to view that creates this problem?

Comment: Almost any page opening was taking more than 20-30secs to open. But since last couple of weeks i have bunch of config changes and weirdly the problem has gone away.

Comment: I suspect the level of nesting is just expected -- the markup in typical modern web pages tends to be *heavily* nested.

Comment: The slow rendering problem is still there. Some pages render faster than other. I guess its to do with level of nesting. But it is  many orders slower than firefox etc. almost to point of being unusable.